# Why do I see “Music Videos” and “TV & Movies” as library options in the Apple Music app in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, itunes, music, appletv, catalina

I find this to be weird: I understand that Apple obsoleted and discontinued iTunes in macOS Catalina and the logic being having one app manage everything — music, apps, videos, podcasts, books and such — was getting to be a confusing thing.

Which is why I found it odd to discover that in the Apple Music app — which is supposed to be just about music — there are library menu options for “Music Videos” as well as “TV & Movies.” Screenshot below:

[image: The Music library sidebar in macOS Music.]

Checking in the Apple TV equivalent, there are some other hidden items — such as “Rentals” and “Home Videos” — but those don’t seem out of place:

[image: The Apple TV Library Sidebar.]

So what the heck are those “Music Videos” and “TV & Movies” library options?

Are they simply coding mistakes/remnants from Apple developers dealing with the headache of splitting up the iTunes library? Or do they serve some real purpose? Because I assure you that after upgrading to macOS Catalina, all of my videos — movies, TV shows, etc… — are accessible without any issue in my Apple TV setup.